# How to autogenerate new _id in target table when migrating a DocumentDB table using AWS DMS to another DocumentDB table

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, aws-dms, aws-documentdb

I have a AWS DocumentDB with schema `my-schema` and table called `my-table` which has a structure something like

```json
{
    "_id": { "FIELD_1" : "001", "FIELD_2" : "A1" },
    "FIELD_1": "001",
    "FILED_2": "A1",
    .
    .
    .
}
```

as you can see that the `_id` contains `FIELD_1` & `FIELD_2`. combination of these two fields are unique for all the records. These two fields formed the composite primary key in the original oracle db that is why when we migrated from oracle to DocumentDB, AWS DMS chose to put that into `_id`.

Now the problem is, we need `_id` to be a mongodb ObjectId instead of a nested json.

What I have tried is:

1. create a source endpoint with my DocumentDB (which contains this bad _id data, in schema `my-schema`).
2. create a target endpoint with the same DocumentDB but with new schema `my-new-schema` and same table name `my-table`.
3. Then I migrate the data from my-schema to my-new-schema using transformations (remove column _id).

But It still replicates the same nested `_id` into the target table.
I have tried both document metadata mode & table metadata mode.
In table metadata mode, it doesn't even transfer data because after it flattens the _id into _id.FIELD_1 & _id.FIELD_2. DMS throws an exception "Document can't have '.' in field names"

I know that I can do this easily using code but if it is somehow possible to achieve my goal using DMS I would prefer that.

or can we achieve this using mongodb commands directly?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about DMS, but I think you can do this using an aggregation query with the $out stage. Project the fields you need, exclude _id, the documents in the new collection will be inserted with the usual ObjectId. Something like this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {$project:
    {_id:0,
    FIELD_1:1,
    FIELD_2:1
  }},
  {$out: 'new_collection'}
])
```